# Show breakline in uigrid

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, json, ui-grid

I'm using uigrid  like below:

```
columnDefs: [                            
           { name: 'CA', field: 'CA', displayName: 'CA', enableCellEdit: false }
]
```

the CA column has data like below :

```
<div> name : Jon ><br /> Job : Barber </div>
```

even that i have `<br />` i got a result as it is , without a break line.

Any solution ? to show the result like  :

```
name : Jon
Job : Barber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this might be close to what you want, user2848242.

[image: angularjs ui-grid html in data]

JavaScript/AngularJS Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ngSanitize']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    rowHeight: 40,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    columnDefs: [{
      name: 'CA1',
      field: 'CA',
      displayName: 'Original CA',
      enableCellEdit: false,
      cellTemplate: '<span ng-bind-html="row.entity[col.field]"></span>'
    }, {
      name: 'CA2',
      field: 'Name',
      displayName: 'Alternative CA',
      enableCellEdit: false,
      cellTemplate: '<div>Name: {{row.entity[col.field]}}<br />Job: {{row.entity["Job"]}}</div>'
    }]
  }
  $http.get('data.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;
    });
}]);
```

The basic idea is, add a `cellTemplate` to your `columnDefs`.  The tricky part is, since HTML is in your data you need to use `ngSanitize` to "trust" the HTML so it'll appear as HTML.  Since it's best to separate HTML from data, for many reasons, I provided an alternative - hence Original CA and Alternative CA columns.

Here's a working Plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/pkoARFr11Q7TmbBIegIT?p=preview.

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any other questions.